# How to replace a word from a string in android

Tags: java, android

I have a string, with value  hi, how r u{name}; 
And also I have an Array of  size 3
I want to find the word " {name} " from the  string and replace it with current array value a[i].
I have try to this code

```
Resources res = getResources ();
String []Questions=res. getStringArray (R.array.faq_ques);

int Questions_Array_length = Questions .length;

for(i=0; i<Questions_Array_length; i++) {
  String Amith= "hi how r u {Name}";
  Amith.replace("{Name}", Questions[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> [public String replace (CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Copies this string replacing occurrences of the specified target
>   sequence with another sequence. The string is processed from the
>   beginning to the end. Parameters target   the sequence to replace.
>   replacement   the replacement sequence. Returns
>
> ```
> the resulting string.
> ```
>
> Throws NullPointerException   if target or replacement is null.

```
Amith = Amith.replace("{Name}", Questions[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something this is what you need

```
        String sentence = "hello what is your name";
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i<words.length; i++){
            if(words[i].equals("Your String")){
                words[i] = "Your New String";
            }
        }

        String newSentence = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<words.length; i++){
            newSentence += words[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Amith = Amith.replace("{Name}", Questions[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question is not clear,I assume that this part is not working `Amith.replace("{Name}", Questions[i]);` meaning that the `string amith` is not getting replaced.you need to do `Amith=Amith.replace("{Name}", Questions[i]);` As String is immutable,**The result of** `String.replace()` **is a new String with the replaced value**.

```
Resources res = getResources ();
String []Questions=res. getStringArray (R.array.faq_ques);

int Questions_Array_length = Questions .length;
for(i=0;i<Questions_Array_length;i++)
{
  String    Amith= "hi how r u {Name}";
  Amith=Amith.replace("{Name}", Questions[i]);
}
```